# Hibernate Implementing a Queue

Tags: multithreading, hibernate

I have a Quartz schedule which is inserting data in TblTransactions table. I want to run another Quartz schedule with multiple instances/threads which will fetch records from TblTransactions, do some processing and delete the records.

How do i ensure that a record fetched by a thread doesn't get fetched by another thread?

Can I integrate oracle advanced queue with hibernate? What else options can I consider?

I am using Hibernate with Oracle 11g.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could get very tricky not to get the same record twice if multiple threads are reading the same table, even if you somehow mark them as fetched in the database (the other thread could read the row before the transaction commits).

The way I would implement this is to use a single thread to fetch the records, then split them up for processing and delegate N records to each processor-thread, and use [Futures](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) or callbacks to track the progress (so if some processor-thread fails, I know to re-submit the records for processing and/or log/email the error to alert admins so they know to check it out in case of invalid data or such).

Either the processor-threads could take care of removing the processed records themselves when they complete (either immediately after a single record has been processed, or remove all in one go after all records have been processed), or you could have a mapping in the fetch-thread to map records to processor-thread, and once the thread finishes successfully, remove all the records it processed.

If the fetching-operation would be called periodically, and there could still be old records in processing, you'd probably need the mapping in fetch-thread -side to know if the fetched records contain such records that are already in processing from an earlier fetch-run.